# Stopwatch and ReadKey don't work properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, stopwatch, console.readkey

I'm working on my multi-threading password cracker, only numbers. It must show how much time has passed to find the password. I used `Stopwatch` to find it, but in functions `Stopwatch` doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;


namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int psw = 14995399;

        Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();

        Thread Thread1 = new Thread(islem1);
        Thread Thread2 = new Thread(islem2);
        Thread Thread3 = new Thread(islem3);
        Thread Thread4 = new Thread(islem4);

        time.Start();

        Thread1.Start();
        Thread2.Start();
        Thread3.Start();
        Thread4.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        time.Stop();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.Elapsed);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void islem1()
    {
        for (int i = 00000000; i < 25000000; i++)
        {
            int psw = 14995399;
            if (i == psw)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Şifre=" + i);

                time.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.Elapsed);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }

    static void islem2()
    {
        for (int i = 25000000; i < 50000000; i++)
        {
            int psw = 14995399;
            if (i == psw)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Şifre=" + i);

                time.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.Elapsed);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }


    static void islem3()
    {
        for (int i = 50000000; i < 75000000; i++)
        {
            int psw = 14995399;
            if (i == psw)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Şifre=" + i);

                time.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.Elapsed);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }

    static void islem4()
    {
        for (int i = 75000000; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            int psw = 14995399;
            if (i == psw)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Şifre=" + i);

                time.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.Elapsed);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a separate `Stopwatch` in each of your thread functions. Don't create a single one and share it between threads.

Comment: This is not *"doesn't work"*, it is *"doesn't compile"*. That's a huge difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your variable

```
Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
```

declared outside the visibility functions. The scope of visibility the var is your function `Main`. You can pass `Stopwatch` as a parameter to your functions:

```
Thread1.Start(time);
```

Or declare it as a class field:

```
class Program
{
    private static Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
    ...
}
```

Note that you have just one `Stopwatch` instance then if you stop it in one thread it'll stopped in all application and elapsed time will not changed after that.

Then you should delete `time.Stop();` from your `Main` method because it can caused the result in cased when your threads works longet then 1 second.

Also it's no reason to call `Thread.Sleep()`. Just delete this lines and your code continues work as expected.

Finally you can delete `Console.ReadKey()` from your thread functions because your main-thread already waits for user input.

The whole solution with configurable threads count can illustrate interesting results for different number of threads. Try the code below which can illustrate work with thread parameters and reduce lines of code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private class BruteforceParams
        {
            public int StartNumber { get; set; }
            public int EndNumber { get; set; }
        }

        private const int password = 14995399;
        private static readonly Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int maxPassword = 100000000;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of threads: ");
            var threadsCountString = Console.ReadLine();
            var threadsCount = int.Parse(threadsCountString);

            var threads = new Thread[threadsCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++)
            {
                var thread = new Thread(Bruteforce);
                threads[i] = thread;
            }

            time.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++)
            {
                threads[i].Start(new BruteforceParams { StartNumber = i * maxPassword / threadsCount, EndNumber = (i + 1) * maxPassword / threadsCount });
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Bruteforce(object param)
        {
            var bp = (BruteforceParams) param;
            for (int i = bp.StartNumber; i < bp.EndNumber; i++)
            {
                if (i == password)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Şifre=" + i);
                    time.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.Elapsed);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your scenario but I think that you no need to get ReadKey in every thread function. Try to delete it and it will continues work as expected I think. Also, delete time.Stop(); line from Main function.

Comment: This isn't going to be all that useful to OP because they call `Stop` on the single Stopwatch instance several times. This will have unexpected results.

Comment: this is a homework for me to understand the time difference between brute force password crack and multi threading password crack.

Comment: OK. Then, you also no need to declare `int psw = 14995399;` in each thread function, you can just declare it as the class field like a `StopWatch` in my answer.
Also it can be interesting to create configurable by threads count system. You can read N from console, creates N treads and pass to each thread start search number `i * 100000000 / N` where `i` is your thread index. It's not your homework but it can be interesting and it'll not take long ;)

Comment: that's a good idea, but now i'm gonna do the password cracker for parallel task thing, i don't know how to use that, and what is the idea of that, this is the last night for the homework :)

Comment: @AhmetÖzdemir I updated my answer with whole solution.

Comment: your code is so complicated for me, because i dont know c# codding, i'm learning it for homework, and as i see we define the thread number, but it must be 4 threads to use.

i have another question

Comment: static void islem1()
        {
            Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
            time.Start();
    
            for (int i = 00000000; i < 25000000; i++)
            {
                int psw = 14995399;
                if (i == psw)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Şifre=" + i);
                    
                    time.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.Elapsed);
                    Console.ReadKey();
}
            }
        }

Comment: this is my first thread, other threads are same like this one. 
when i start the stopwatch, and stop it, i think it starts timer from 0 on other functions. i need to have the total time to find the password

Answer (score 1):

How do you think `time.Stop();` going to work inside your function body `islem1()` or any other since you have defined the stopwatch inside `Main()` function body. You are bound to get compilation error saying `time` doesn't exist in current context.

```
static void islem1()
{
        .............
            time.Stop();  // this line of code
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Rather, you can create a separate watch per method and report that

```
static void islem1()
{
      StopWatch time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      time.Stop();  // this line of code
      Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", time.Elapsed);
      Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be difficult to extract meaningful timings using a single `Stopwatch` instance.

You might chose to make your timing measurements using a different pattern that uses a new `Stopwatch` for each measurement.

```
void Main()
{
    var t1 = new Thread(_ => {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        DoSomething();
        Console.WriteLine("took {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    });
    var t2 = new Thread(_ => {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        DoSomethingElse();
        Console.WriteLine("took {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    });
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
    t1.Join();
    t2.Join();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

void DoSomething()
{
    //do something
}

void DoSomethingElse()
{
    //do something
}
```